# How to populate textbox depending on which radio button is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textbox

I am working with html and jquery. I have a form in which I have few radio buttons and few text box. I need to populate my textbox depending on which radio button I am selecting.

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Nmqk/121/)

Now what I need to do is - After selecting `Process` button If I am selecting `UpdateTest` radio button, then I need to add `hello` in the `AddNodeText` box but if I am selecting `DataTest` radio button, then I need to add `world` in the `AddNodeText` box and apart from that, I don't need to do add anything in `AddNodeText` box.

Is this possible to do using jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
$('input[name="client"]').click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('id') === 'updatetest')
    {
        $('#conf').val('hello');
    }
    else if ($(this).attr('id') === 'datatest')
    {
        $('#conf').val('world');
    }
    else
    {
        $('#conf').val('');
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4Nmqk/122/)

Answer (score 0):

This is nicely done using data attributes.

Set a data attribute

```
<input type="radio" data-text="hello"></input>
```

Add data attribute on click.

```
$(".boxes").on('click', function() {
 var text = this.getAttribute('data-text');
 $("input#conf").val(text);
});
```

Here is your Fiddle, I've updated it and its working. http://jsfiddle.net/4Nmqk/123/